# Openlayers vector layer

Tags: vector, dictionary, openlayers

I want to have a vector layer of the world, which shows the country borders, states and their names in English. Is there a layer that exists that I can control the colours?

Cloudmade doesn't let me quite do this, nor does openstreetmap and a bunch of others. I'm thinking I might need to create a raster image and overlay that except I dont know where to get an accurate EPS/vector map I can edit and overlay.

Running out of options!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have different options depending of your needs:

1. The easiest one is to use a public
   WMS service that offers the
   information you need. You can check
   catalogues like [this one](http://www.ogc-services.net/) or a
   Google search like [this](http://www.google.es/search?hl=ca&q=inurl%3Aservice%3Dwms+inurl%3Agetcapabilities+world+borders).  If
   your are lucky to find a service
   that suits you, just add it as a WMS
   layer in OpenLayers as described in
   this [example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/lite.html).
2. If you can't find a public service, you will have to serve the
   geographic data yourself. You have
   to find a dataset of the world
   countries (the most common formats
   are ESRI shapefile and KML).

   - If you find a shapefile ([try here](http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/world_borders.php)), you will
     have to serve it via a map server like
     [MapServer](http://mapserver.org/) or [Geoserver](http://geoserver.org/).
     Both are pretty straightforward to
     set up, but choose the one that suits you best (MapServer is a CGI and Geoserver is Java-based). Once you have configured a WMS service with the countries data, you can add it to your OpenLayers app following the previous example.
   - If you can't or don't want to use a map server and you have a KML file of the world countries, you can also add a vector layer to OpenLayers from a KML file, as described in [this example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/kml-layer.html). Be careful, because all geometries will be rendered in the user's browser (with SVG or VML) and for large datasets, this can be a performance issue. Check [this example](http://thematicmapping.org/playground/openlayers_choropleth_kml.php) to see it in action.

I hope this give you a few clues.